# Is a pointer to function pointer convertible to a void pointer and vice versa?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

```
void f(void);
void (*pf)(void) = f;
void *p = &pf;
(*(void (**)(void))p)();
```

I tried to find the part in the C standard (draft) document that states about such conversion. But I failed to do so in my last 30 minutes.

How is the conversion between a void pointer and a pointer to function pointer defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

§6.3.2.3/p1:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   object type.

§6.2.5/p20:

> A *pointer type* may be derived from a function type or an object
>   type, called the *referenced type*. [...] A pointer type is a 
>   complete object type.

"pointer to function" is an object type, so "pointer to pointer to function" is a pointer to an object type, and so is convertible to and from "pointer to `void`" by §6.3.2.3/p1.